# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. (Autolayout)

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I'm new to storyboard and trying to use auto layout to display an image view in a tableview cell with simple constraints. But when the image displayed, the warning come out in the console. The image can be display but the warning is still there. I tried to put the image view into a view, but its still the same. I don't understand what is the problem in my constraints.

[image: storyboard View]

[image]

```
2021-04-12 12:37:38.901847+0800 Tunai[48387:14397746] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c0af30 UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0.width == 70   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c08460 UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0.width == UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c09400 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe7f7fbf450 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c094a0 V:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe7f7fbf450 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c339d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe7f7fbf450.height == 90.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000c08460 UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0.width == UIImageView:0x7fe7f7fbf5e0.height   (active)>
```

Comment: Have you kept the row height as `UITableView.automaticDimension` or some hardcoded number ?

Comment: @PrasadParab yes. I did set it as automaticDimension. But when I remove it, it still show the same warning

Comment: From the Warning, it seems that the ImageView height and vertical margins do not add up and match the superview's height. You probably need to make one of the margins as 'greater than' for the autolayout to function correctly.

Comment: @PrasadParab I just realised when I make it to "greater than", the image size will be unstable when I scroll it down.

Comment: In that case, you will need to keep the constraints as you had then before and check if the UITableView is taking the automatic row dimensions properly.

Comment: @Oxford212 - Try keeping your bottom constraint at `equal to` but set its Priority to `999`.